# Fragment layout only showing first element (TextView)

Tags: android, android-fragments

i have two fragments that show depending on whether the phone is in landscape or portrait mode. however both only show the first element but nothing else after like EditText or Buttons. Is there a fix for this?

pm_layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/portrait_message"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="100px"/>


    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter First Time"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter Second Time"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <fragment
        android:name="com.android.madpracticaltest.LM_Fragment"
        android:id="@+id/lm_fragment"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <fragment
        android:name="com.android.madpracticaltest.PM_Fragment"
        android:id="@+id/pm_fragment"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_main"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Never use `px`, use `sp` for text. Also, LM_Fragment is above PM_Fragment with a weight of 1 which means it takes up more space. There is not enough room for everything most likely.

Answer (score 4):

in `pm_layout`, you have the `LinearLayout` with `orientation="horizontal"` and its children have width `match_parent`, so you should only see the first `TextView`

Comment: THANKS! Such a silly mistake on my side -.- will mark as correct as soon as Stack allows.